# slowly changing dimension in MDX/OLAP

Tags: mdx, olap, olap-cube, iccube

I have got an OLAP cube that has purchased per date, per vendor and some other dimensions.

Below a sample of the data. The vendor is identified by the unique id VendorID:

```
Date        CCID    GLID    CatID   VendorID    Amount
31-3-2012   659     55      25      807         124.5
14-5-2012   425     74      1       1452        371.53
1-4-2012    353     55      106     1648        26.79
2-7-2012    339     78      25      1275        1208
8-7-2012    460     66      41      4311        763.25
```

The vendor itself has a score with values 1-good, 2-average, 3-poor, 4-unattended. These scores vary over time.

Example for vendor 807:

```
VendorID    VendorIDDate    Score
807         1-1-2012        4-unattended
807         27-2-2013       2-average
807         1-4-2014        3-poor
807         31-12-2014      1-good
```

Now when I start a query I would like to count the number of vendors per Score for a specific slicer on GLID, CCID and CatID on a certain date.

What is the best way to model this?

I know I can add the score to the basic fact table using a look-up for each date, but I assume there is a much better way.

Comment: Ralph Kimball classical : 'The data warehouse toolkit' is an excellent entry point to see how to solve this king of problems in the db... later in icCube :-)

Comment: imho, the best solution is adding a Vendor_Score column in the fact_table. Everything else is more complicated.

Comment: Ok, I still was wondering about using a TIME dimension with a "period bucket" and using the fact link functionality: the normal fact data showing for example first day of the month and last day (period = month) and the linked table showing the valid period for the status.

I will leave this open for now and go for your suggestion.

Thanks for your advice.

Comment: Is it possible that on 1-1-2015, the Vendor 807's status switches back to bad? If yes, do you overwrite the earlier value corresponding to "bad", or add a new record for this vendor?

Comment: I do not overwrite the value. The idea is that statuses change over time for a vendor so you can track improvement or deterioration.